# Partial class and edmx

Tags: c#, entity-framework, assemblies, partial, edmx

My `edmx` file generate some `partial` classes. I want extend functionality adding one property, but `edmx` file is in another assembly. In this case they are like two unrelated classes.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit another `type` from the entity type `edmx` has generated and add your property to the inherited one.

Answer (score 1):

you can Create a new class in your assembly that will extend/inherit the partial class and add properties and methods as you like